# Call again abstract inherited method from another class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract-factory

I am using abstract factory pattern. I need to call an abstract method which is called the `HelperClass`.

For example: I have two abstract derived classes. I create `ClassA`, then `ClassA` calls `TakeAction` method. `TakeAction` method needs to create another method which uses `HelperClass` and call`class the method`SolveProblem`.

Here is my question: How can I call again a `ClassA` method in the `HelperClass`? Because SolveProblem have some logic and it will be decide to return or not.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var classA = new ClassA();
        classA.StartOperation();
    }
}

public abstract class ClassAbstract {
    public abstract void StartOperation();

    public void TakeAction() {
        var helper = new HelperClass();
        helper.SolveProblem(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }

    public abstract void WeekDayOperation();
    public abstract void WeekEndOperation();
}

public class ClassA : ClassAbstract {
    public override void StartOperation() {
        TakeAction();
    }

    public override void WeekDayOperation() {
    }

    public override void WeekEndOperation() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassAbstract {
    public override void StartOperation() {
        TakeAction();
    }

    public override void WeekDayOperation() {
    }

    public override void WeekEndOperation() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class HelperClass {
        public void SolveProblem(DayOfWeek day) {
        //Problem solved. I need to call "CallThisMethod" who called this helper class
        //How to I Call
        switch(day) {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                ClassA.WeekEndOperation();
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                FridayOperations();
                break;
            default:
                ClassA.WeekDayOperation();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void FridayOperations() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what problem you're trying to solve. What do you mean when you say "How can I return again ClassA methods?"

Comment: factory or abstract factory are creational patterns. Your implementation does not look like it. It looks more like a convoluted Interface. Why do you need the HelperClass? is there a specific reason?

Comment: DavidN: My point is, How can I call that one of caller instance methods in any function? 

MongZhu: yes, in main method normally, I create multiple derived class. So I decided to use abstract factory. But if interface is better solution, I am open it :) I need Helper class, because it actually manage scenarios. So I want to handle all scenario operations in a class. Actually my swicth statement has 7 case and only 2 of them need to call, caller class method again.

Comment: your inheritance from an abstract class is like an interface already. An interface is an completely abstract class. :) you can use this inheritance to solve your problem via polymorphism. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to pass an instance of type: `ClassAbstract` as parameter into the method `SolveProblem`. You can use this variable then to call the method.

```
public void SolveProblem(DayOfWeek day, ClassAbstract c)
{
    //Problem solved. I need to call "CallThisMethod" who called this helper class
    //How to I Call
    switch (day)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            c.WeekEndOperation();
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            FridayOperations();
            break;
        default:
            c.WeekDayOperation();
            break;
    }
}
```

To close the circle you need to pass the current instnace (`this`) when calling this method in the base implementation of `TakeAction` in the `ClassAbstract`:

```
public abstract class ClassAbstract
{
    public abstract void StartOperation();

    public void TakeAction()
    {
        var helper = new HelperClass();
        helper.SolveProblem(DayOfWeek.Sunday, this);
    }
```

By the phenomenon of [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) the correct implementation of the override will be called. In you example from above it will be the overrides of the methods `WeekEndOperation` and `WeekDayOperation` of the class `ClassA`